# Translucent window becomes corrupted under Mavericks (Mac OS 10.9)

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I'm having a very strange problem for which I have very little information to offer. Having searched the web to no avail I really just hoping that someone here has some idea of what can be happening.

I have a Mac application that displays a "head-up" display in a translucent window. This window changes size dynamically to fit the contents.

Under previous versions of Mac OS this works perfectly. Under Mavericks this works 95% of the time, however occasionally it will suddenly become corrupted and part of the window will lose it's transparency and become solid grey. At this point the only other window in the application also becomes corrupted in a similar fashion!

There's no apparent way to reliably reproduce the problem, it appears to be random.

I realise that this is very vague, but I don't have any more solid information to offer at this point. Has anyone else seen this sort of issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not developing on my Mac, but I have occasional image corruption in translucent parts of the OS interface. It seems to occur after my Mac has waken from sleep.  Random noise appears in the images where translucent gray background should be.  I never saw this before upgrading to Mavericks.  OS-level memory corruption is likely.